# require process.env in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a `.env` file and it has

`ABC='abc'`

and when I do `process.env.ABC` in my app.js I can get the `abc` value. How do I require it to be use in my models' files? I do the same thing `process.env.ABC` in my models file, it got undefined. I assume I have to require it?

Comment: You should be using something like dotenv package to load env variable from .env file. Are you using any of those ? You will have to npm install dotenv  and then require the same to load environment variable wherever you want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to `require` the `.env` file and store in the a variable when you start your app. Once you have this, you can either pass it as a method argument or wrap your models in `module.exports = (env) => { return myModel; }`

In express, it would be something like

```
const env = require('dotenv').config({path: 
'/custom/path/to/your/env'});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  app.env =  env;
});
```

Now, you can access the `env` by passing `req` to the models and `get` the `env` using `req.app.get('env')`

Comment: what is the use of this .env thing? usually I'll just use .json or .js like config.json or better config.js and just require it like var config = require('config').whateverKey;

Comment: They all serve the same purpose, just with a different approach. I generally use a cfg/index.js which is overwridden by a environment variable set while starting the app. Only keep cfg/index.js or a dev variant in SCM.

Comment: SCM means what?

Comment: source control management. Variants are git, mercurial, svn. Also, if my answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it.